# jQuery: notification of visible html elements

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I want to be able to find out when a page element is on or off the viewers screen. Specifically, I'd like to be able to "turn off" an html 5 canvas (Processing.js) script if the user has scrolled past the canvas and back on when it is visible again in the users browser.

Does this make sense? I am thinking that there must be some way for the DOM to fire off a notification via ajax to turn on and off the canvas script.

thanks.

///////////
EDIT (final code)
//////////
Here is the final code that I used:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
   var $canvas = $('#canvas');
   var pos     = $canvas.offset();
   var total = pos.top + $($canvas).height();
   var wndtop  = $(this).scrollTop();

   if(wndtop <= pos || wndtop >= total ){ 

   }

});
```

Comment: Try http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport , it lets you select elements depending if they are currently viewable you could check it on every scroll event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach an event handler to the `window scrolling`. Like

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
   var $canvas = $('#hlogo');
   var pos     = $canvas.offset();
   var wndtop  = $(this).scrollTop();
   var wndleft = $(this).scrollLeft();

   if(wndtop <= pos.top && wndleft <= pos.left)
      $canvas.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using DOM properties `element.y`, `element.style,height` and `window.scrollY`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adjust the code in the link below to your needs.
[Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scroling)